# how to store the output of ubuntu command line with python

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I need to run the following command line (in Linux Ubuntu) from a Python script and store the results into a variable

I am using the following code

```
dir = 'labels.txt'
for dir in subdirs:
    args = "tail -1 %s"%(dir)
    output = subprocess.check_output(args, shell = True)
```

I have the following error message: `No such file or directory`. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for your help
Fred

Comment: yes. My mistake sorry. I have modified the code

Comment: The assignment to `dir` serves no purpose, since `dir` is then used as a loop variable in the `for` loop.  You might as well remove that line from the post.  What's relevant is `subdirs`, which is unknown.

Comment: See my answer that provides with a subprocess wrapper and also a correct for loop that walks over '.txt' files in a given directory. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean `subprocess.check_output`, you're supplying relative directory. When you run a command with `subprocess.check_output(args, shell=True)`, it is executed in your home directory - `/home/<username>/`.
There, it is trying to access the file `dir`, which may not exist.

If you try to run the same command in shell, you'd get this output
`tail: cannot open '<filename>' for reading: No such file or directory`

To counter this, I'd suggest you use absolute paths in your program. An example would be as follows

```
import os
import subprocess


directory_to_iterate_through = "/absolute/path/to/directory"

for file in os.listdir(directory_to_iterate_through):
    filepath = os.path.join(directory_to_iterate_through, file)
    args = "tail -1 %s" % (filepath)
    output = subprocess.check_output(args, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use package `command_runner` which will deal with timeouts, encoding etc on Unix and Windows platforms and provides the exit code so you know when the command fails.

Grab it with `python -m pip install command_runner`

Use it with

```
from command_runner import command_runner

all_output = []
file= 'labels.txt'

command = "tail -1 {}".format(file)
exit_code, output = command_runner(command, shell=True, timeout=30)
if exit_code == 0:
   all_output.append(output)

print(all_output)
```

If you happen to need to iter over files in a given directory, you might use `ofunctions.file_utils`.

Grab it with `python -m pip install ofunctions.file_utils`

Use it like:

```
from ofunctions.file_utils import get_files_recursive

files = get_files_recursive('/my/folder', ext_include_list='.txt')
for file in files:
    exit_code, output = command_runner('tail -1 {}'.format(file), timeout=30)
    if exit_code == 0:
        print(output)
```

DISCLAIMER: I am the author of command_runner package.